# Круг на яндекс картах для сайта

Tags: javascript, html, яндекс-карты

Яндекс выдаёт код для размещения карты на сайте в двух видах JS и iframe.
Есть код в котором реализован круг на карте в JS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=ВАШ_КЛЮЧ_АПИ" type="text/javascript"></script>
     
      <script>
         ymaps.ready(init);
         function init() {
         var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {center: [55.76, 37.64], zoom: 10});
         var myCircle = new ymaps.Circle([
           [55.76, 37.60],
           10000
         ]);
         myMap.geoObjects.add(myCircle);
         }
      </script>
      <style type="text/css">
         html, body, #map {
         width: 99%;
         height: 99%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
   </body>
```

Но для моего сайта подходит только в iframe. Подскажите как сделать такой же круг в iframe.